# What is the RFC 2822 date format in PHP (without using date('r'))?

Tags: php, date, date-format

Is `date('D, j M Y H:i:s O')` equivalent to `date('r')` ([RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) date) in PHP? I'm asking because `'r'` seems to be non-working with the *format* parameter of [date_parse_from_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php).

Comment: What is your exact question? If `date_parse_from_format()` is not working for you with the `r` parameter, please mention that in your post and add some of your code.

Comment: @Rijk Edited. Hope I'm clearer now.

Comment: It's still not clear (for me) what your question is.

Comment: Change j to d and you got it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `date(DateTime::RFC2822);` if you want dates in the RFC 2822 format.

Comment: This produces: `D, d M Y H:i:s O`

Comment: @Yeroon Echoing DateTime::RFC2822 confirms that `'D, d M Y H:i:s O'` is what I needed with date_parse_from_format.

Comment: `$this->_add_hdr('Date', sprintf(date(DateTime::RFC2822)));` produces this SPAM warning: `0.4 INVALID_DATE           Invalid Date: header (not RFC 2822) ` Ideas how to fix it please?